# How to measure power consumption of Arduino Uno onboard ADC module?

Tags: arduino, adc, power-consumption

For a project, I am using Arduino Uno onboard SAR ADC module. I want to calculate the power consumption by the ADC module. The way I am thinking to calculate it is AVCC*ICC. Here, AVCC is the supply voltage for the ADC module and ICC is the current drawn from the power supply. Now, if my clock is 16MHz then at active mode I'll consider the ICC is 9.2mA according to table 28.3 (attached) from the datasheet. My confusion is

1. If I set the ADC module reference voltage at 1.1 V (Typical) then should my AVCC will be 1.1 V or still 5V?
2. For 1.1 V internal reference voltage, will the ICC be 9.2mA at 16MHz clock?
3. Is there any way to experimentally measure the power consumption by this ADC module?
   I am adding the ADC characteristics table 28.9 from the datasheet as well.

Thanks!
[image]

[image]